# select a value from dataframe with for loop

Tags: python, loops, select

I'm using python and I wonder how to select an individual value from a dataframe. I need to select this value from an interaction and then use it in an equation, so is a variable number.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
df

           B
  A                     
 114    0.1452
 117    0.1855
 122    0.2005
```

Then, I use a list containing values of column A

`My_list = [114, 117, 122]`

and I need to extract the values of column B, one at a time, so I'm using:

```
for i in My_list:

    z = df.at[[i],'B']
```

these give me : `TypeError:'[114]' is an invalid key`

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
z = df.at[i,'B']
```

A better way to do this:

```
for z in df['B'].values:
    # do something with z
```

Comment: that produces the following message: `ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers`

Comment: and If I try to use another dataframe: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'at'`

Comment: check the `type(df)` and share the output please.

Comment: The output is: `Out[79]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: ok try `df.at[114,'B']` and see if that works. I tried reseting my index to a column and did `.at` and it worked. So not sure what problem you are actually facing.

Comment: When I run `df.at[114,'B']` it doesn't work and appears: `TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [114] of <class 'int'>`

Comment: oh so your Index column is a String. Fair.. just change to `df.at[str(i),'B']` and that should work. Or change the datatype for index column.

Comment: See if the 2nd part `for z in df['B'].values:` works for you or not.. it should ideally.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPacheco  that made my day :)